# Remove ends of string entries in pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching

I have a pandas Dataframe with one column a list of files

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('fname.csv')

df.head()

filename    A    B    C
fn1.txt   2    4    5
fn2.txt   1    2    1
fn3.txt   ....
....
```

I would like to delete the file extension `.txt` from each entry in `filename`. How do I accomplish this?

I tried:

```
df['filename'] = df['filename'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-4])
```

but when I look at the column entries afterwards with `df.head()`, nothing has changed.

How does one do this?

Comment: is your data `'fn1.txt'` or `fn1.txt`? so do you have quoted strings as your data?

Comment: @EdChum I see no quotes

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex `.txt$'` ( `$` - [matches the end of the string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 2, 1: 1}, 
                   'C': {0: 5, 1: 1}, 
                   'B': {0: 4, 1: 2}, 
                   'filename': {0: "txt.txt", 1: "x.txt"}}, 
                columns=['filename','A','B', 'C'])

print df
  filename  A  B  C
0  txt.txt  2  4  5
1    x.txt  1  2  1

df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.replace(r'.txt$', '')
print df
  filename  A  B  C
0      txt  2  4  5
1        x  1  2  1

df['filename'] = df['filename'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-4])
print df
  filename  A  B  C
0      txt  2  4  5
1        x  1  2  1

df['filename'] = df['filename'].str[:-4]
print df
  filename  A  B  C
0      txt  2  4  5
1        x  1  2  1
```

EDIT:

`rstrip` can remove more characters, if the end of strings contains some characters of striped string (in this case `.`, `t`, `x`):

Example:

```
print df
  filename  A  B  C
0  txt.txt  2  4  5
1    x.txt  1  2  1

df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.rstrip('.txt')

print df
  filename  A  B  C
0           2  4  5
1           1  2  1
```

Comment: I get the following `AttributeError`: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Try cast column `filename` to `string` - `df['filename'] = df['filename'].astype(str)`

Comment: Even casting the column as a string, none of these methods work

Comment: It works with dataframe in my solution? `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 2, 1: 1}, 
                   'C': {0: 5, 1: 1}, 
                   'B': {0: 4, 1: 2}, 
                   'filename': {0: "txt.txt", 1: "x.txt"}}, 
                columns=['filename','A','B', 'C'])` ?

Comment: What is your version of `pandas`? `print pd.show_versions()`

Comment: I get an idea. Maybe help reset_index. Try `df = df.reset_index()`, because maybe first column `filename` is not column, but `index`.

Comment: '0.18.0' is the version for pandas

Comment: Super. And I think help reseting index.

Comment: For `type(dropped_newdf['filename'].values)`, I get `numpy.ndarray`

resetting the index didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110901/discussion-between-jezrael-and-shanzhengyang).

Comment: Sorry, but what you get `type(dropped_newdf.loc[0, 'filename'])` ?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) to remove the endings:

```
df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.rstrip('.txt')
```

should work

Comment: don't know it should've worked but the question remains does your data have quotes or not?

Comment: When I use `df.head()`, I see no quotes

Comment: So, when I try the above code, I get the following error 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str''

Comment: what version of pandas are you using? vectorised `str` accessor was added in `0.15.0` I think

Comment: I think `rstrip` method can be problematic, if last character of file contain `t`, `e` or `x`. Then this char is removed. Try `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 2, 1: 1}, 
                   'C': {0: 5, 1: 1}, 
                   'B': {0: 4, 1: 2}, 
                   'filename': {0: "test.txt", 1: "x.txt"}}, 
                columns=['filename','A','B', 'C'])`

Comment: Sorry, not `e`. only chars `t` and `x`.

Answer (score 8):

You may want:

`df['filename'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['filename'][:-4], axis = 1)`

Comment: How about if instead of a fixed size of -4 you I need something more flexible say, get rid off the last words after the comma or period?

Answer (score 2):

use list comprehension

```
df['filename'] = [x[:-4] for x in df['filename']]
```

Comment: i want to delete last or first character if  the last or first character is "X".
Example please

Answer (score 2):

## update 2021 + speedtest

Starting from pandas 1.4, the equivalent of [str.removesuffix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix), the [pandas.Series.str.removesuffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removesuffix.html) is implemented, so one can use

```py
df['filename'].str.removesuffix('.txt')
```

### speed test

tl;dr: the fastest is

```py
dat["fname"].map(lambda x: x[:-4] if x[-4:] == ".txt" else x)
```

In the speed test, I wanted to consider the different methods collected in this SO page. I excluded `rstrip`, because it would strip other than `.txt` endings too, and as regexp contains conditional, therefore it would be fair to modify the other functions too so that they remove the last 4 chars only if they are `.txt`.

The testing code is

```py
import pandas as pd
import time

ITER = 10


def rm_re(dat: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    """Use regular expression."""
    return dat["fname"].str.replace(r'.txt$', '', regex=True)


def rm_map(dat: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    """Use pandas map, find occurrences and remove with []"""
    where = dat["fname"].str.endswith(".txt")
    dat.loc[where, "fname"] = dat["fname"].map(lambda x: x[:-4])
    return dat["fname"]


def rm_map2(dat: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    """Use pandas map with lambda conditional."""
    return dat["fname"].map(lambda x: x[:-4] if x[-4:] == ".txt" else x)


def rm_apply_str_suffix(dat: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    """Use str method suffix with pandas apply"""
    return dat["fname"].apply(str.removesuffix, args=(".txt",))


def rm_suffix(dat: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    """Use pandas removesuffix from version 1.6"""
    return dat["fname"].str.removesuffix(".txt")


functions = [rm_map2, rm_apply_str_suffix, rm_map, rm_suffix, rm_re]
for base in range(12, 23):
    size = 2**base
    data = pd.DataFrame({"fname": ["fn"+str(i) for i in range(size)]})
    data.update(data.sample(frac=.5)["fname"]+".txt")
    for func in functions:
        diff = 0
        for _ in range(ITER):
            data_copy = data.copy()
            start = time.process_time()
            func(data_copy)
            diff += time.process_time() - start

        print(diff, end="\t")
```

The output is plotted below:

[image: runtime for different functions]

It can be seen from the plot that the slowest solution is the regexp, and the fastest is the `pandas.Series.map` with a conditional. In later versions of pandas, this may change and I'd expect an improvement in `pandas.Series.str.removesuffix`, as it has a greater potential in vectorization.

Pandas had to be installed from the source as of 2021-11-30, because version 1.4 is in the developement stage only. I installed it by following the instructions from [pandas dev repo](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas), by cloning the project and installing with `python setup.py install`.

My machine:

- AMD Ryzen 5 2400G with Radeon Vega Graphics, 3.60 GHz
- Windows 10 20H2
- Python 3.10.0, pandas.**version** '1.4.0.dev0+1267.gaee662a7e3', numpy.**version** '1.21.4'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You can simply do:

```py
df['filename'] = df['filename'].astype('str').str.rstrip('.0')
```

Remember to add `.astype('str')` to cast it to str otherwise, you might get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```