# remove specific characters from time stamp

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a rather odd time format and the data frame `df` with the column `TIMESTAMP`:

```
2016-10-25T09:34:52.051713+01:00
2016-10-25T09:46:14.051620+01:00
2016-10-25T09:51:16.052435+01:00
....
```

but I need to use the data as time information. In the first place, I would like to get rid of the last 13 characters such that it looks like

```
2016-10-25T09:34:52
2016-10-25T09:46:14
2016-10-25T09:51:16
....
```

To do so, I tried

```
df['TIMESTAMP'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['TIMESTAMP'][:-13], axis = 1)
```

from [Remove ends of string entries in pandas DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001787/remove-ends-of-string-entries-in-pandas-dataframe-column/37003236)

but I receive the error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

which I do not understand. I'm just fresh in python but I don't see much I've done wrong?

Comment: When you remove the last part, you might get into trouble when DST comes into play. This will change the timezone and you might have inconsistent data after your operations. You might consider to, instead of trimming the timestamp, to correct it and convert it into UTC.

Comment: thanks for the hint! What is DST?

Comment: DST stands for [_Daylight Saving Time_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strict answer to your question is to use the `str` accessor, which can take a slice, just like a normal string, and which will apply that slice to every value in the `Series`:

```
data = ['2016-10-25T09:34:52.051713+01:00',
        '2016-10-25T09:46:14.051620+01:00',
        '2016-10-25T09:51:16.052435+01:00']

s = pd.Series(data)

print(s.str[:-13])
```

Output:

```
0    2016-10-25T09:34:52
1    2016-10-25T09:46:14
2    2016-10-25T09:51:16
```

*However*, I think what you want is actually `pd.to_datetime`, which will (within reason) infer the format of your data and convert it into `datetime` objects:

```
print(pd.to_datetime(s))
```

Output:

```
0   2016-10-25 09:34:52.051713+01:00
1   2016-10-25 09:46:14.051620+01:00
2   2016-10-25 09:51:16.052435+01:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is to use a list comprehension :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIMESTAMP' : ["2016-10-25T09:34:52.051713+01:00", "2016-10-25T09:46:14.051620+01:00"]})

 TIMESTAMP
0  2016-10-25T09:34:52.051713+01:00
1  2016-10-25T09:46:14.051620+01:00

df['TIMESTAMP'] = [x[:-13] for x in df['TIMESTAMP']]
```

Output :

```
TIMESTAMP
0  2016-10-25T09:34:52
1  2016-10-25T09:46:14
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to always use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) package if you deal with any kind of dates. As of Python3.7, functions [`fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat) can digest your ISO format directly, while [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) can convert to any thinkable time format. (For Python3.6 or lower see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281975/convert-timestamps-with-offset-to-datetime-obj-using-strptime) answer).

In your case with timestamps written in `df['TIMESTAMP']`:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
df['TIMESTAMP'].apply(lambda x: dt.strftime(dt.fromisoformat(x), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
```

will do the trick and give your desired output:

```
             TIMESTAMP
0  2016-10-25T09:34:52
1  2016-10-25T09:46:14
2  2016-10-25T09:51:16
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the transformation statement with below code

```
df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].apply(lambda x: x[-4:])
```

This will apply the transformation function to the entire column named time stamp and save it back with the same column name

Comment: Thank you! The last bracket is too much. But I receive the error: "KeyError: 'TIMESTAMP'. What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'TIMESTAMP': [
            '2016-10-25T09:34:52.051713+01:00',
            '2016-10-25T09:46:14.051620+01:00',
            '2016-10-25T09:51:16.052435+01:00'
        ]
    }
)
df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].apply(lambda x: x[:19])
```

BTW, are you sure you don't need to keep the information of timezone?